# django-autocomplete-light: How to cache choices?

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

I have my own City model (not django-cities-light) with more than 2M records in MySQL table. Each time I'm starting to type in autocomplete field, CPU load on htop table jumps over 200% on mysqld process, so it looks that script requests the table on each autocomplete.

I'd like to put the table into memcache to avoid this, and here is what I have so far:

#### autocomplete_light_registry.py

```
import autocomplete_light
from django.core.cache import cache, InvalidCacheBackendError
from cities.models import City

def prepare_choices(model):
    key = "%s_autocomplete" % model.__name__.lower()
    try:
        qs = cache.get(key)
        if cache.get(key): # return if not expired
            return qs
    except InvalidCacheBackendError:
        pass
    qs = model.objects.all()     # populate cache
    cache.set(key, qs, 60*60*24) # if expired or not set
    return qs

class CityAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    search_fields = ['city_name']
    choices = prepare_choices(City)
autocomplete_light.register(City, CityAutocomplete)
```

But it still keeps on requesting mysql.

Any suggestions?

#### UPDATE

I tried to set the cache for cities table in django shell, but the process breaks with **Segmentation fault** message.

```
>>> from django.core.cache import cache
>>> qs = City.objects.all()
>>> qs.count()
2246813
>>> key = 'city_autocomplete'
>>> cache.set(key, qs, 60*60*24)
Segmentation fault
```

But I was able to put smaller tables into cache, and I hope to overcome this problem, so the answer is still needed.

Comment: Could you post the list of SQL queries made by one autocomplete request ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

> cache.set(key, qs, 60*60*24) Segmentation fault

this happened because query is to big.
You will need to cache this AFTER its filtered.

this is how I did this. Not perfect but did work nicely with 500 elements.

```
def get_autocomplete(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        results_list = MY_model.objects.filter(title__contains=q).all()
        results = []
        for result in results_list:
            results.append(result)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'Nothing to see here!'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return http.HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

Found this on net somewhere.

You will need at best first 10 elements as rest will pop out of screen.